# using linq to sql to get a limited selection of rows, possibly without joins

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to get the count from a table using linq. I have a table foo which contains a bar id. the bar table has barProperty. In sql i might do a join, but i was wondering if there was a nice linq way to say, get all rows in foo, where foo's bar has a barProperty of 73. Something in sql similiar to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo
LEFT JOIN ON bar.barid=foo.barid
where bar.barProperty=73;
```

I may have done it wrong(im new to linq) but i have a linq to sql dbml that i have made an association with the appropriete ids. Using Parent child.

Comment: What have you *tried*? The answer is "Yes" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like the following;

```
int recordsCount = (from x in foo
             join y in bar
             on x.barid equals y barid
             where x.barProperty == 73).Count();
```

I'm pretty sure you can do it without a join but I'm more of a LINQ to Objects guy so I'm just giving the most standard example possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have context set properly, you don't need join at all:

```
var NumberOfFoos = context.Bars.First(x => x.Id == 73).Foos.Count();
```

Comment: I thought i had my context set up correctly, but possibly not. I couldnt get this to work for me, but +1 anyway.